# Decode MongoDB resumeToken BSON

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I recently started testing out ChangeStreams, the new feature added in MongoDB 3.6 for monitoring changes in a collection, and I cannot get the resumeToken decoded.

I have tried:

```
resumeToken = change["_id"]
# Check validity
bson.is_valid(resume_token)
```

`Error: TypeError: BSON data must be an instance of a subclass of bytes`

Okay so I guess that means I need to access the binary data directly.

```
print("is valid:", bson.is_valid(resume_token['_data']))
```

`is valid:False`

I am confused because looking at the [ChangeStream Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/#change-stream-output) the `_id` field is supposed to be a BSON document:

```
{
   _id : { <BSON Object> },
   "operationType" : "<operation>",
   "fullDocument" : { <document> },
   "ns" : {
      "db" : "<database>",
      "coll" : "<collection"
   },
   "documentKey" : { "_id" : <ObjectId> },
   "updateDescription" : {
      "updatedFields" : { <document> },
      "removedFields" : [ "<field>", ... ]
   }
}
```

The reason that I want to decode it is to monitor the timestamps. Does anyone know how to decode the resumeToken BSON document?

Edit: Example resumeToken

```
{'_data': b'\x82Z\xc2\x8c\xf3\x00\x00\x00\x01Fxtime\x00x\x80\x00\x01b\x87\xf6\x97\xb1d_id\x00dZ\xc2\x8c\xf3`\x88\x05\x00\x01\x98\xa4\xd8\x00Z\x10\x04\xac\x1eBC{\xf5E\xc4\xa0\xd8\x89\xca\x830\x99\x9e\x04'}
```

Comment: make sure `resume_token` has a field `_data`. Normally, it' `data`. Maybe for timestamp, you only need `resume_token._id` for [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/)?

Comment: @Valijon yes it has a field _data, 'data' returns a key not found error. I'll update with an example.

Comment: ok. Try this: `bson.BSON.decode(resume_token)` [https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#bson.BSON](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/index.html#bson.BSON). Posible workaround: Each time you modify a document, update a field with timestamp. So it can be read from `resume_token['fullDocument']`

Comment: `print("token: ", bson.BSON.decode(resume_token))` results in a "TypeError: argument to _bson_to_dict must be a bytes object"

Comment: The [object size isn't the same with the length of data](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/ba7c95a9dfe1b9fea2e2a0bd117fd319545e5e30/bson/__init__.py#L420) in your resume token. Can you add print-out of the document for the change event as-is to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to decode the resumeToken BSON document?

By default [MongoDB Drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/) would have decoded this BSON document for you. As you can see there are two document keys within : `_data` and `_typeBits`. However, the value that is contained within these keys are binary data.

For example in the current version of MongoDB (3.6.3):

```
{ _id: { "_data": BinData(0, "...")
         "_typeBits": BinData(0, "...") 
       }
}
```

The binary data is constructed on the MongoDB server and is an object of [KeyString](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3.6.3/src/mongo/db/storage/key_string.h). The object is encoded with (in sequence): `clusterTime`, `documentKey`, `UUID`. See also [resume_token.cpp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/3.6.3/src/mongo/db/pipeline/resume_token.cpp#L67-L89)

As of current versions of MongoDB drivers, there is no available method to decode the `KeyString` object on client/application side.

**Note:** Currently there is an open ticket [SERVER-32283](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32283) related to this.

> The reason that I want to decode it is to monitor the timestamps

Depending on what you need this timestamps for, because the content of the encoding starts with `clusterTime` you can actually sort the binary chronologically.

Comment: I was hoping to construct a resumeToken on the fly so that I could start applying operations from a specific point in time. I thought that if I could deconstruct the structure I might be able to do this.

Comment: You could cache a resume token and continue from then onwards. I would suggest to open a new question describing your use case. i.e you may be able to benefit from using event driven system schema.